# Why won't Opera play this <audio> MP3 (but will play this OGG)?

Tags: html, audio, opera

The tracks both play fine if accessed directly but only the OGG will play in the `<audio>` player.

**YAY!**

```
<audio controls preload="none">
<source src="//www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

**BOO!**

```
<audio controls preload="none">
<source src="//www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>
```

http://jsbin.com/tapisike

Comment: Which version of Opera, and what OS? mp3 is supported in Opera 25+ if the OS has support for it, see http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2014/09/bookmarks-arrive-opera-beta-25/.

Answer (score 0):

because ogg is an open format, but mp3 is encumbered by patents and would require opera to pay a license fee to play them in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Opera does not support mp3, but does support wav and ogg.  The list of audio tags and browser support can be found at [w3schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)